# How do i display an image instead of text for a ? on an xml form for ODK collect?

Tags: image, forms, odk, javarosa

Since odk collect uses utf-8, the language that i would like the questions of the form to be in would be displayed one character at a time vs. conjoined. instead of displaying text for the question, i want the question to display an image which will be on the question text formatted properly. Is there anyway this can be done, are there any good tutorials or information out there that can help me accomplish this?

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa">
  <h:head>
    <h:title>firstform</h:title>
    <model>
      <instance>
        <data id="build_firstform_1375472795">
          <meta>
            <instanceID/>
          </meta>
          <field_name/>
          <field_age/>
          <field_location/>
        </data>
      </instance>
      <itext>
        <translation lang="eng">
          <text id="/data/field_name:label">
            <value>**<img src="Q1.png" >**</value>
          </text>
          <text id="/data/field_name:hint">
            <value>What is your name (last, first)?</value>
          </text>
```

the bolded code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><h:head xmlns="">
<h:title>images</h:title><model>
<instance>
<data id="1">
<some_text/>
<image_test/>
</data>
</instance>
<itext>
<translation lang="eng">
<text id="/data/image_test:label">
<value>picture test</value>
</text>
<text id="/data/image_test:a">
<value form="image">jr://images/p1.jpg</value>
</text>
<text id="/data/image_test:b">
<value form="image">jr://images/p2.jpg</value>
</text>
</translation>
</itext>
<bind nodeset="/data/image_test" type="select1"/>
</model>
</h:head>
<h:body xmlns="">
<select1 ref="/data/image_test">
<label ref="jr:itext('/data/image_test:label')"/>
<item>
<label ref="jr:itext('/data/image_test:a')"/>
<value>a</value>
</item>
<item>
<label ref="jr:itext('/data/image_test:b')"/>
<value>b</value>
</item>
<item>
<label ref="jr:itext('/data/image_test:c')"/>
<value>c</value>
</item>
</select1>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```